# R: filter dataframe by column name with a string match in a different dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, string-matching

I have two data frames shown below. What I would like to do is subset the first data frame to keep only columns whose column name appears in a column from the second data frame, as well as columns with a partial string match to one specific string. The actual data is much longer with more varied names so I need something that can be easily applied to all of them.

df1:

| abc1 | abc2 | acd1 | abd1 | acd2 | xxx1 | xxx2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |

df2:

| sample | total |
| --- | --- |
| abc1 | 5 |
| abc2 | 4 |

desired df3:

| abc1 | abc2 | xxx1 | xxx2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 7 |

Here is what I tried

```
keep <- df2$sample
df3 <- df1 %>% select(contains(keep))
```

which kept all columns who had a partial string match, not a complete string match

```
keep <- df2$sample
df3 <- filter(df1, grepl(keep,colnames(df1)))
```

which gave me an error that input 1 must be of size 1037 or 1, not 160
(1037= #of rows in df1, 160= #of columns)

Additionally, this does not deal with the xxx columns. For that I have tried the following

```
cols <- colnames(df1)


keep <- list.append(keep, colnames(df1) %>% select(contains("xxx")))

keep <- list.append(keep, filter(colnames(df1), grepl("xxx",df1)))

keep <- list.append(keep, cols %>% select(contains("xxx")))

keep <- list.append(keep, filter(cols, grepl("xxx",cols)))

keep <- list.append(keep, grepl("xxx",cols))
```

resulting in the error

```
no applicable method for x applied to an object of class "character"
```

where x is the function like filter

```
keep <- list.append(keep, grepl("xxx",colnames(df1)))
```

which appended a true/false result for each column name to the list.

I am not attached to this way of doing things, so any and all solutions are appreciated, a list just seemed like the easiest way to me.

Comment: How does your partial string matching work? Why do you want to get `xxx1` and `xxx2` but not `abd1` or `acd2`? What's the algorithm behind it?

Comment: xxx are controls where as the other letters are samples. In a previous step I had to filter out samples, so controls were excluded. Now I need to keep only the samples that met criteria and recombine them with the controls.

Comment: So, should the `xxx` column always be included?

Comment: yes in df3 but not df2

Comment: I'm not sure, what you are exactly asking for... `df1 %>% select(contains(df2$sample), contains("xxx"))`?

Comment: this selected only columns from df 1 that contained xxx and not any from df2

Comment: `Warning in if (ignore.case) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: Sorry... my mistake: `df1 %>% select(contains("xxx"), df2$sample)` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Martin Gals comment

`df1 %>% select(contains("xxx"), df2$sample)`